# Overloaded method with string parameter is never called, the method with object parameter is called instead

Tags: c#, overloading

I don't understand why method `Value(string s)` is never called for elements 
of `List<string>` when the list is passed into `ToString<M>(List<M> list)` method. Below is my test code extracted from LinqPad.

I have no problems calling a proper `Value()` method while iterating through lists outside of `ToString<M>(List<M> list)`  method.

Thank you!

```
void Main()
{
    var list1 = new List<string>{"one","two","three"};
    var list2 = new List<object>{1,2,3};
    var list3 = new List<long>{1,2,3};
    "Strings".Dump();
    ToString<string>(list1);
    //list1.ForEach(i=> Value(i)); // proper overload of Value() is called 
    "Objects".Dump();
    ToString<object>(list2);
    //list2.ForEach(i=> Value(i));
    "Longs".Dump();
    ToString<long>(list3);
    //list3.ForEach(i=> Value(i));
}

public static string ToString<M>(List<M> list) 
{

    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach(M i in list)
    {
        sb.AppendFormat("{0},", Value(i));
    }
    var str = sb.ToString();
    str.Dump();
    return str;
}


public static string Value(string s)
{
    "String".Dump();
    return "'" + s + "'";
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public static string Value(object o)
{
    "Object".Dump();
    return o.ToString();
}
```

Here is the output. It shows that Value(string s) is never called

```
Strings
Object
Object
Object
one,two,three,
Objects
Object
Object
Object
1,2,3,
Longs
Object
Object
Object
1,2,3,
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the binding to `Value()` within `ToString<M>` is done *at compile-time*.  Since there's no constraint for `M`, the best overload it can find is `Value(object)`.

In order to bind to `Value(string)` you'll have to either cast the parameter to `string` or to make `i` `dynamic` in your `foreach` loop:

```
foreach(dynamic i in list)
{
    sb.AppendFormat("{0},", Value(i));
}
```

That will then bind `Value(i)` *at run-time* which will then choose whether to use the `string` or `object` overload.